# Looking to have a precise number

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm currently working on a java project and I can't find a solution to my problem. So this happens, I divide a number by 45 and I want it so when the number is 46 I don't get a big decimal but 2.. Like it would round it..

Here's what I currently have.

```
int pages = number / 45;
```

I can't find any solution to this even tho it seems really simple.
Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: `int pages = (int) Math.ceil(number / 45.0);`

Comment: Works thanks a lot Matthew :D

Comment: @MatthewDiana You should post that as an answer. Get credit for your work dude :)

Comment: @4castle Reputation is like our [fiat currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar#Silver_and_gold_standards). Once you realise that it has no intrinsic value, you'll end the desperate hunt. Not being an addict in the first place is certainly not a bad thing

Comment: You want a **whole** number *(a number without fractions; an integer)*, not a **precise** number, e.g. `1.022222222222222` would be a more precise number. There is no null precision value for that number without using [fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Forms_of_fractions).

Comment: @Gendarme If someone makes a good answer, they deserve to have more privileges on the site. The community treats rep like it *does* have value, so therefore it has value. Otherwise, gold likewise would have no intrinsic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing two `int`s will use [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), so 46/45 will yield 1. If you want to ceil the result, you'll need to perform a floating point division:

```
int pages = (int) Math.ceil(number / 45.0);
```

Comment: Did you just leech a comment??

Comment: I don't really want to click solved because Matthew's the one who really helped me.. XD

Comment: If he ever decides to post an answer, then you can change it and select his. In the meantime, go ahead and select it.

Comment: Remember, votes are not to be taken personally, whether they are upvotes or downvotes. Answers are supposed to be written as answers; not as comments. Whether this question was *supposed to* be answered or simply closed and ignored is another discussion.